# How to send custom object to web service & Convert it to custom object

Tags: c#, web-services

I am new to webservice
I have webservice. I need to send custom object(TBatch) as object to webservice & now webservice need to convert this object to custom object(TBatch).
How to achieve this I am getting following error. 
There was an error Genreating XML Document.

**Please find following code:**
**Web Service**

```
[WebMethod]
public string SplitBatchObj(Object batchObj, string scanStationID)
{
    string s = "Test";
    TBatch m_cTBatch = (TBatch)batchObj;
    return s;
}
```

**Calling the web service**

```
public int CallService(TBatch obj)
{
     Object objBat = (TBatch)obj;
     //call service method;
     string s = srv.SplitBatchObj(objBat, "Test String");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original assumption is incorrect. You don't have to send your TBatch instance as an object. Do the following instead:
Define TBatch class in the separate DLL (class library). Reference this library in your client and server projects. Then you can change Web Service signature to get argument of type TBatch

Comment: Hi Leo, I Know that I followed your process ( DLL Reference ) but it is not working. so decided to convert it to Object & send it webservice. Then web service need to convert it custom object. When I tried with first method I getting cannot No parameterless constructor

Comment: Casting to/from object is a wrong way to do it. Please, add details what "isn't working" when you use typed parameter